# convert array from inside of returned object into select item list js

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-select

I've looked at several examples here on how to do this and the answer still alludes me.

I have an ajax call that returns an object with a couple properties as well as an array of other objects.  I want to take 2 properties from each internal object to create a list.  right now, I have code that looks like this:

```
myMethod: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(){
        $('#mySelectList').append($('<option></option>').text(data.Name).val(data.ID));
    });
}
```

I have tried `JSON.stringify(data.Name)` as well, which I believe is needed here, but I think I am accessing the properties incorrectly.  The object that is returned looks like this in my chrome dev tools:

```
Object {BooleanProperty1: true, BooleanProperty2: true, Rows: Array[9]}
```

and when i drill down into the rows:

```
0: Object
    ID: 1
    Title: "SomeTitle"
    SomeOtherProperties: propertyData
    //more properties
2: Object
    ID: 2
    Title: "SomeOtherTitle"
    SomeOtherProperties: propertyData
    //more properties
//more objects
```

How can i access the properties inside this array to use them when creating the list?

Comment: Is the single/double quote a typo in `$('<option></option>")`?

Comment: yes.  corrected.  this is not a cut and paste from the project

Comment: hey can you please put jsfiddle,?

Comment: @Himesh Aadeshara Juan C. has given me an acceptable answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` it's the response or the complete array and what you need its each of the elements inside of it, for that you need to specify the index and `element` parameters in the function and read the values from the `element`

[$.each() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
 $.each(data.Rows, function(index, element){
    $('#mySelectList').append($('<option></option>').text(element.Name).val(element.ID));
  });
```

Comment: this is not working for me.  I think I may need an inner loop.  When i do an "each" on it, it is adding three (blank) items to my list, i assume for `BooleanProperty1`, `BooleanProperty2`, and `Rows`

Comment: @USER_8675309 change it to `data.Rows`

Comment: Perfect.  I get it.  Thanks so much